# Komodo: debug toolbar disappeared

Tags: debugging, toolbar, komodo

look at the screenshot at https://snipboard.io/9lWtnp.jpg - it shows
my current state of Komodo. I don't know how I arrived there and my
problem is: How do I get back a menu where I can run / debug a
program?

I remember having a toolbar with the usual buttons for run /
step over / step into etc., but somehow I managed to lose it and am
unable to get it back.

Help, please.
M'

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: The 'alt' key seems to toggle the menu in and out of sight. Once in sight, in the debug menu I can click on Go/Continue and debugging starts - and even the debug toolbar appears at the bottom.

M'